# Codeigntier: redirect within config/routes.php file?

Tags: codeigniter, routes, redirect

I'm updating a website and have a bunch of old URLs that need to be rerouted to their new equivalents. I want to do this server-side (rather than with .htaccess)

It would be neat if in my config/routes.php I could just declare something like this:

```
$route['old_url_1'] = redirect('/new/url/1', 'location', 301);
$route['old_url_2'] = redirect('/new/url/2', 'location', 301);
$route['old_url_3'] = redirect('/new/url/3', 'location', 301);
```

Obviously it doesn't work, but is anything like this possible, ie. keep this code in my routes file (more logical) or do I need to go and set up functions in some controller?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You need to create something(method at controller), that will redirect browser with 301-code. Something like this:

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Redirectme extends MY_Controller {

    public function index($url=false) {
     if($url===false)
         redirect('/');
     redirect('/new/url/'.$url,'location',301);
    }

}

?>
```

and add to route.php

```
$route['old_url_(:any)'] = "redirectme/index/$1";
```

Anyway, best practice to redirect via .htaccess (because it will not call even php-module from webserver).

Comment: OK, thank you. No way to keep in the routes file though?

Comment: @Inigo no, You can send vars to some controller's method only, if You want use default CI routing system. You can define vars to send by Yourself `$route['my/old/url.html'] = "mystore/item/apple";` for example

Comment: OK, thank you. Now I have another damn problem. Some of the old URLs have spaces in them, and (of course) codeigniter's routing can't handle spaces. Yay.

Comment: But thanks for your help... got it working with a work-around.

Comment: @Inigo try to use %20 for spaces or send all URL segment to method with `(:any)` wildcard (ex. `$route["old-url/(:any)/(:any)"] = "mystore/redirect/$1/$2";`)